# error "cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code"

Tags: python, opencv

This line of the code get the error
classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
coded with VSCode, Python 3.10, Windows 10 Education

the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
thres = 0.45 # Threshold to detect object
nms_threshold = 0.2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# cap.set(3,1280)
# cap.set(4,720)
# cap.set(10,150)
 
classNames = []
classFile = "ModelosDNN/classes.txt"
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip("n").split("n")
 
#print(classNames)
configPath = "ModelosDNN/yolov4-tiny.cfg"
weightsPath = "ModelosDNN/yolov4-tiny.weights"
 
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)
 
while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
    bbox = list(bbox)
    confs = list(np.array(confs).reshape(1,-1)[0])
    confs = list(map(float,confs))
    #print(type(confs[0]))
    #print(confs)
 
    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox,confs,thres,nms_threshold)
    #print(indices)
 
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = bbox[i]
        x,y,w,h = box[0],box[1],box[2],box[3]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,h+y), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(img,classNames[classIds[i][0]-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
 
    cv2.imshow("Output",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Every time i try to use the detectModel the same error appear, have something to do with the OS?